# How to do dependency injection of a library with gradle?

Tags: android, gradle

We are developing an Android project that depends on some Java libraries. For testing purposes we want to be able to use a stubbed variant which will include a different jar.
How to do this with gradle ?

I have been trying something with flavours but now only the 'flavour' is built, not the normal build...

Answer (score 0):

You would probably be better off using a lightweight DI container like Google Guice than trying to do this with the build system.

https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/

You can define a testing module and a production module that binds the project to the test and production classes respectively.

If you really want to do it with gradle, I can't think of a very nice way to do this. One way would be to define a new configuration (call it testAndroid), and exclude all of the production jars from it, and replace them with the testing jars. Then you can still use the java plugin to build it. You can define a new archive that will publish the testing jar when uploadArchives is run. Here is a stubeed out example:

```
configurations{
    testAndroid extendsFrom compile
    testAndroid.exclude(group: 'my.company.production') 
}

dependencies{
    compile group: 'my.company.production', name: 'prod-jar', version: '1.0'
    testAndroid group: 'my.company.test', name: 'test-jar', version: '1.0'
}

task testJar(type: Jar){
    //build the jar
}

artifacts{
     archives testJar
}
```